# c++ cannot convert ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} to ‘std::string (*)[3]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string (*)[3]’}

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to make a [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) AI in C++. I am currently making a function to check if the winstate of the game, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
61:34: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} to ‘std::string (*)[3]’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string (*)[3]’}
   61 |         cout << HasWon(Board[3][3], Length);
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~^
      |                                  |
      |                                  std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
main.cpp:6:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int HasWon(std::string (*)[3], int)’
    6 | int HasWon(string GameBoard[3][3], int boardLength);
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that it has to do with char and strings, but I don't have any idea how to implement it in my current program. Here’s the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int AIMove(int PlayerMove);
int HasWon(string GameBoard[3][3], int boardLength);
int main () {
    int Length = 3;
    string Board[Length][Length] = {
        {" ", " ", " "},
        {" ", " ", " "},
        {" ", " ", " "},
    };
    int NodeMap[Length][Length] = {
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
    };
    int NodeNumber = 1;
    for(int h = Length - 1; h >= 0;h--) {
        for(int d = 0; d < Length; d++) {
            NodeMap[h][d] = NodeNumber;
            NodeNumber++;
        }
    }

    int Player;
    bool HasMoved = false;
    bool run = true;
    while(run) {
        // Prints Tic Tac Toe board to the screen
        for(int h = 0; h < Length; h++) {
            cout << " ";
            for(int d = 0; d < Length; d++) {
                cout << Board[h][d];
                if(d < Length - 1) {
                    cout <<"||";
                }
            }
            if(h < Length - 1) {
                cout << "\n---------\n";
            }
        }
        // Gets player input
        cout << "\n choose a number 1-9 to place an X: ";
        cin >> Player;

        // Adds it to the board
        HasMoved = false;
        while(!HasMoved) {
            for(int h = 0; h < Length; h++) {
                for(int d = 0; d < Length; d++) {
                    if(NodeMap[h][d] == Player && Board[h][d] == " ") {
                        Board[h][d] = "X";
                        HasMoved = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!HasMoved) {
                cout << "\n choose a number 1-9 to place an X: ";
                cin >> Player;
            }
        }
        cout << HasWon(Board[3][3], Length);
    }
}

int AIMove(int PlayerMove, int boardLength);

// Checks if anyone has won yet. 0: nothing has happend, 1: tie, 2: X win, 3: O win.
int HasWon(string GameBoard[3][3], int boardLength) {
    int xNumber = 0;
    int oNumber = 0;

    // Checks for vertical wins
    for(int d = 0;d < boardLength; d++) {
        xNumber = 0;
        oNumber = 0;
        for(int h = 0;h < boardLength; h++) {
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "X") {
                xNumber++;
            }
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "O") {
                oNumber++;
            }

            if(xNumber == boardLength ) {
                return 2;
            }
            if(oNumber == boardLength ) {
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checks for horizontial wins
    for(int h = 0;h < boardLength; h++) {
        xNumber = 0;
        oNumber = 0;
        for(int d = 0;d < boardLength; d++) {
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "X") {
                xNumber++;
            }
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "O") {
                oNumber++;
            }

            if(xNumber == boardLength ) {
                return 2;
            }
            if(oNumber == boardLength ) {
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checks for diagonal wins
    xNumber = 0;
    oNumber = 0;
    for(int i = boardLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(GameBoard[i][i] == "X") {
            xNumber++;
        }
        if(GameBoard[i][i] == "O") {
            oNumber++;
        }

        if(xNumber == boardLength ) {
            return 2;
        }
        if(oNumber == boardLength ) {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    xNumber = 0;
    oNumber = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < boardLength; i++) {
        if(GameBoard[i][i] == "X") {
            xNumber++;
        }
        if(GameBoard[i][i] == "O") {
            oNumber++;
        }

        if(xNumber == boardLength ) {
            return 2;
        }
        if(oNumber == boardLength ) {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    // Checks for a tie
    xNumber = 0;
    oNumber = 0;
    for(int h = 0;h < boardLength; h++) {
        for(int d = 0;d < boardLength; d++) {
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "X") {
                xNumber++;
            }
            if(GameBoard[h][d] ==  "O") {
                oNumber++;
            }

            if(xNumber+oNumber == boardLength*boardLength) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `HasWon(Board[3][3], Length)` -> `HasWon(Board, Length)` and `int Length = 3;` -> `const int Length = 3;`. I don't know what your intention with the `[3][3]` indices is and array sizes must be compile-time constants in standard C++. `int` without `const` cannot be a constant at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that the type of the expression `Board[3][3]` when passing as a call argument is `std::string` while the type of the function parameter `GameBoard` is actually `‘std::string (*)[3]`. This is because of `string [3][3]` **decays** to `string (*)[3]` due to **type decay**.

Thus there is **mismatch** in the type of the parameter of the function `HasWon` and the argument passed.

Also note that in standard C++, the size of an array must be a compile time constant. So in you code:

```
int Length = 3;
string Board[Length][Length]; // This is not standard C++
```

The statement `string Board[Length][Length];` is not standard C++ because `Length` is not a **constant expression**.

To **solve** this you should add a top-level `const` to `Length` and pass the argument `Board` instead of `Board[3][3]` as shown below:

```
//-vvvvv---------------------------> const added here
   const int Length = 3;
//----------------vvvvv------------> Changed to Board instead of Board[3][3]
   cout << HasWon(Board, Length);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/UkUpK7ReZ).

Another alternative (better) would be to use [std::vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)#Vector).